# Regex optional matching

Tags: java, regex

#### Pseudo/dummy-code that will be matched against:

```
RECOVERY: 'XXXXXXXXX' is UP
PROBLEM: 'ABABABAB' on 'XXXXXXXXX' is WARNING
PROBLEM: 'XXXXXXXXX' is DOWN
RECOVERY: 'ABABABAB' on 'XXXXXXXXX' is OK
PROBLEM: 'ABABABAB' on 'XXXXXXXXX' is DOWN
```

#### Goal

Capture `XXXXXXXXX`(without the single-quotes) but do **NOT** capture `ABABABAB`

#### Best attempt so far:

```
(M: \'|Y: \')(.*)(?:\' )(?:is)
```

Is it even possible to achive the goal above, and if yes, then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lookahead only to check if the string matched is before `is`:

```
'([^']*)'\\s*(?=\\bis\\b)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gJ6kR1/1)

Breakdown:

- `'` - single apostrophe
- `([^']*)` - capture group matching 0 or more characters other than `'`
- `'\\s*` - a single apostrophe and 0 or more whitespace symbols
- `(?=\\bis\\b)` - a lookahead making sure there is a whole word `is` after the current position (after the `'` with optional whitespaces)

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/xcfRjs):

```
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("'([^']*)'\\s*(?=\\bis\\b)");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher("RECOVERY: 'XXXXXXXXX' is UP");
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**UPDATE**

I used a lookahead only because you used a [***non-capturing group***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group) in your original regex : `(?:is)`. A non-capturing group that has no quantifier set or any alternation inside seems reduntant and can be omitted. However, people often get misled by the name *non-capturing* thinking they can exclude the substring matched by this group from the overall match. To check for presence or absence of some text without matching, a lookaround should be used. Thus, I used a lookahead.

Indeed, in the current scenario, there is no need in a lookahead since it makes sense in case you need to match subsequent substrings that start wiyh the same sequence of characters.

So, a better alternative would be

```
'([^']*)'\s*is\b
```

Java:

```
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("'([^']*)'\\s*is\\b");
```

Comment: Why bother using a lookahead?  You're using a capturing group to extract the part you want, so what does it matter if the `is` is consumed?

Comment: @AlanMoore What is your solution? Im note sure to understand.. Isnt the lookahead the better solution hère? Since there could also be a ABABAB instead of XXXXXX

Comment: @YassinHajaj:  I'm not saying you shouldn't check for `is` after the quoted word, just that you don't need to use a lookahead.  Copy [NEO-xx's regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34032684/20938) into the code above and you'll get exactly the same result.  The lookahead and the word boundaries are both unnecessary complications.

Comment: @AlanMoore Ok I get it, Im new to RegEx sorry. So hes capturing a group for nothing if I get it right when he does not need to capture it? Speaking about the "is" group of course

Comment: @YassinHajaj: I added my explanation why I chose that lookahead. Also, I posted my answer at midnight and went straight to bed, I shouldn't have done that, perhaps (both :)).

Answer (score 2):

Following regex should work

```
\'([^']+)\'\s+is
```

all the matches will be stored in matcher groups array